# "Error loading documents" in Firebase Database

Tags: database, macos, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing error when trying to access **Database** menu item within **Firebase console**.

It's a new Database with literally couple records of data but screen keep spinning for ages and then returns message "***Error loading documents***". In the same time I'm able to access **Authentication** menu item without any problem.

*Note*: *I'm using MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.15.4 and Safari browser 13.1*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a **Firewall** which is blocking my access to **Database** section within **Firebase Console**. Since I'm working on the corporate Mac I don't have control over it.

**Workaround** that works for me: use alternative private device ie. Mobile Phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Add-Block fixed mine

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was Safari. I was able to access the data programmatically but not via the web UI. Also, Safari worked well for the first few days I used it. I found that when I switched to Brave, I could see all my documents in the console.

Answer (score 0):

On safari it doesn't work. I had to switch browser to Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

Since last Firebase update it doesn't work on Safari anymore, don't know why I tried everything (Ad-block, firewall, ...). Even on mobile.

You have to use another browser to access your firestore docs...

April 16, 2021 : issue fixed, works again on Safari

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was using windows Microsoft edge, I was using adblocker extension and I turned it off, but it didn't work. Then I opened the console on a chrome browser on a physical device and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to access the console in my work laptop with a vpn running in the background. Turn off that vpn and refresh console page. You should be able to see all your documents now.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33145531)

Comment: It clearly provides a solution. What else do you need?