# Unable to load documents in firestore subcollections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add documents to a firestore subcollection but I am finding an error for unable to load. The log sometimes shows a timeout error but other times does not.

This is the error message on functions log:

Function execution took 60007 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Most of the time there is no error message, only that the documents fail to load as seen in the provided image.

Any ideas?
Here is the code I'm running.

```
exports.postRepos = (req,res) => {

    const newRepos = {
        userHandle: req.user.handle,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
    };

    db.collection('userss')
    .doc(req.params.handle)
    .collection('log')
    .add(newRepos)
    .then((doc) => {
        const resRepos = newRepos;
        resRepos.ReposId = doc.id;
        res.json(resRepos);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({error: "Server error. Something went wrong"});
        console.error(err);
    });

}
```

[image: Fire]

Comment: Please edit the question to show more completely what the error message is, and what line it refers to.

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is the code in my functions dir that I deploy to firebase on the CLI. I am then using postman to make the api call. I'm very new to this so apologies if my terminology is off.

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025566/error-loading-documents-in-firebase-database), it looks like you are behind some firewall.